# How to resolve a CORS error on OKTA Hosted Signout

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, okta

I'm trying to add OKTA to my React application. I've gotten sign-in to work fine. But I'm struggling with Signout.

Setup:
I added OKTA to my project following [these instructions](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/sign-into-spa/react/before-you-begin/) from OKTA.

This mostly worked, but included these instructions for invoking the sign-in

```
  const { authState, authService } = useOktaAuth();
  const login = () => authService.login('/profile');
```

`authService` could not be found. So I went to the [OKTA Example](https://github.com/okta/samples-js-react) and changed it to

```
  const { authState, oktaAuth } = useOktaAuth();
  const login = async () => oktaAuth.signInWithRedirect();
```

This also means that

```
authService.signOut();
```

changed to

```
oktaAuth.signOut();
```

Problem:
As I said above I'm able to login just fine. `authState.isAuthenticated` resolves to True.

However when I try to sign out, React reports an "Unhandled Rejection (AuthApiError)" error:

[image]

The console reports these errors:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://dev-7869221.okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/revoke' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

POST https://dev-7869221.okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/revoke net::ERR_FAILED

Uncaught (in promise) AuthApiError
```

I cloned the OKTA example code down, and hard-coded in my application details. Login/Logout works just fine on the demo app. When I log out the configuration object, they match. So I conclude:

- My OKTA Application is configured correctly.
- The Sample app is doing something I haven't noticed
- The OKTA Documentation is out of date for these details.

For completeness my source code and package.json are below.
The application was created with `create-react-app` using the typescript template.

```
export const config = {
    clientId,
    issuer: `https://${domain}/oauth2/default`,
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/login/callback',
    scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email'],
    pkce: true,
    disableHttpsCheck: false,
};

const oktaAuth = new OktaAuth(config);

const CALLBACK_PATH = '/login/callback';

function App() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Security oktaAuth={oktaAuth}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path={CALLBACK_PATH} component={LoginCallback}/>
                    <Route path={'/'} component={Main} exact/>
                    <Route path={'/orgList'} component={OrgList}/>
                </Switch>
            </Security>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default App;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { useOktaAuth } from '@okta/okta-react';

function Main() {
    const { authState, oktaAuth } = useOktaAuth();

    const login = async () => oktaAuth.signInWithRedirect();
    const logout = async () => oktaAuth.signOut();

    if( authState.isPending ) {
        return (
            <>
                <div>Loading authentication...</div>
            </>
        );
    } else if( !authState.isAuthenticated ) {
        return (
            <>
                <div>
                    <button onClick={login}>Login</button>
                </div>
            </>
        );
    }
    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={logout}>Logout</button>
        </>
    );
}

export default Main;
```

```
{
  "name": "okta-test-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@okta/okta-auth-js": "^4.5.0",
    "@okta/okta-react": "^4.1.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.19",
    "@types/node": "^12.19.9",
    "@types/react": "^16.14.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.10",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.6",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env PORT=3000 react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to add your hostname in Okta as a "Trusted Origins". To do this Login to Okta Admin > Security > API > Trusted Origins > Click on Add Origin and enter your app url e.g http://127.0.0.1:3000

### see document:
https://support.okta.com/help/s/question/0D51Y00007w9P8f/implicitcallback-returning-authapierror-screen-in-single-sign-on?language=en_US

### https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/error-codes/

### https://devforum.okta.com/t/cors-issues-while-testing-on-device/857/2

Comment: Didn't even consider this since the OPTIONS response came back with a 200. Thanks!