# 400 error during sign out from OKTA and React application

Tags: reactjs, okta, http-status-code-400

I setup sample react project that uses OKTA as single sign on. everything works fine except sign-out. I am getting weird CORS issue on sign-out of my sample OKTA and react example.
here is the code https://github.com/okta/samples-js-react/tree/master/okta-hosted-login

[image]

I followed the suggestion here and added the hostname in Okta as a "Trusted Origins".
[How to resolve a CORS error on OKTA Hosted Signout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65377823/how-to-resolve-a-cors-error-on-okta-hosted-signout).

[image]

Basically, it is working on my personal laptop, but not working same setup on my office laptop and getting errors.
Any suggestions?

Access to fetch at 'https://dev-45510191.okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/revoke' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: Check if all required parameters are passed inside the request payload

Comment: hi Philipp, thanks for reply.
actually i didn't have params to configure, below snippet code we are invoking for logout! 

import { useOktaAuth } from '@okta/okta-react';
const { authState, oktaAuth } = useOktaAuth();
oktaAuth.signOut({ postLogoutRedirectUri: basename });

Comment: hi Ram, can you check in a network tab what the parameters are for this call? Maybe something is missed b/c of misconfig, just to eliminate this possibility